# How to compute XOR of a vector in verilog with a given delay

Tags: vector, verilog

I'm trying to calculate XOR of `reg[63:0] vec` and I found out that it can be done with the following line:

```
assign u = ^vec;
```

But is there any way to compute XOR of a vector by a given gate delay ?

Comment: something like: `xor #(4) x1(u,vec[0],vec[1],...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assign statement can have an option delay:

```
assign #DELAY u = ^vec;
```

Where DELAY is a number or parameter, or some other constant expression.